# Share a Class Set of Bluetooth Keyboards with Multiple Classes

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, ipad

Background: I teach 12 STEM classes and I have 28 bluetooth keyboards (one class set). Every student has their own iPad. I have labelled each keyboard with a unique number from 1-28. The keyboards are Logitech K380s.

I've spent a long time in each class' first lesson to pair each student with a numbered keyboard with the aim that for the rest of the year, the students in each class just walk into the classroom and automatically connect with "their" keyboard. With this approach, each keyboard is paired with 12 separate iPads, but only connected to one iPad at a time.

However, in the second week of lessons, it looks like many iPads are not connecting. The iPads have kept the pairing in their list of previously paired devices, but the keyboards won't connect. I have triple confirmed that each student has correctly selected their pre-assigned and previously paired keyboard.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth remains paired even when you power down. You actually have to specifically unpair the device, or it will try to pair with the last paired device!

So, before the students leave, they should unpair their keyboards, shut them off so they don't pair again, and the next class should be able to pair without too much problem.

Like I use a earpiece/mic with bluetooth, so I don't need to hold the phone up to my ear. If I shut both devices off, when they power back up they're paired.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Just to clarify: the only way to do this is to teach the students how to pair/unpair? If so, this is going to be a big ask of the younger primary (elementary) students!

Comment: I'm not absolutely positive, as there are at least 5 versions of BT. But to the best of my knowledge, it seems so. These are STEMS classes. Unless it's 1st and second graders, they should have the aptitude to pair BT. I assume they can read a short set of instructions and follow it. If not, yes, pairing could be problematic.

Comment: Yes, I do have some 1st and 2nd grade classes.
A bigger issue I've found though is that pairing all the keyboards at once is almost impossible because each keyboard is the same name in the available devices list. I think I'm going to have to get wired keyboards instead. Thanks @Brian for your help.

Comment: @ Mr C Seems like pretty deep material for 6-7-year-olds. But, it's never too early to start learning. Ok, you might consider a keyboard for each student. I'm not aware of wired mobile keyboards, unless you attach a USB C<>USB A adapter to a PC keyboard. I'm not positive that would even work.  I'll have to try it now, though. It's a very tough problem. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. You can look here https://hearinghealthmatters.org/waynesworld/2013/bluetooth-101-part-iii/